# Integer composition in exactly $T$ parts with maximum addend constraint.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, combinations, integer-partitions

In how many ways an integer $N$ can be partitioned into exactly $T$ parts such that

$T = \lfloor N/K \rfloor + 1$

$N = A_1 + A_2 + \cdots+ A_T$ where order matters

$0 \lt  A_i \leq K$

$ N \bmod K \neq 0 $

I mean I have a recursive formula

$F(N, K) = \sum_{i=1}^k F(N-i, K - 1)$ if $K > 1$

$F(N, 1) = 1$ for $N > 0$ and $ N \leq K$

$F(N, K)$ is counting number of ways in which this can be done.
Can this be computationally improved?

Comment: When "order matters" the sums are called compositions rather than partitions.  Here you are restricting the *size* of parts as well as how many there are.  When you say "exactly $T$ parts", do you mean to exclude the possibility that $A_i = 0$ for some parts?

Comment: I mean to say, exclude $A_i$ for all parts. Thanks, I didn't know composition

Comment: I would add an explicit definition of $F(N,K)$ as "counting ways" and clarify whether you assume $K$ divides $N$ exactly or that $T$ will involve the greatest integer of $N/K$.  Note that when $N$ is exactly divisible by $K$, rarely will $N-1$ be exactly divisible by $K-1$.

Comment: N is never divisible by K. And I have made all the required changes

Answer (score 0):

I think that given your recursion the orders of the $A_i$ matter.

Notice $N=TK-K$.

If we let $B_j=K-A_j$ then we just want to count the partitions of $K$ into $T$ parts, this is just $\binom{K+T-1}{T-1}$

Comment: I am sorry, but you seem to have assume $\lfloor N/K \rfloor $ = $N/K $, which is not the case. I have made the reuqired changes. I am sorry for the confusion

Comment: it was not a confusion, you asked a different question and then you changed it.